# Secret variables in Variable groups are not accessible to self hosted build agents which do deployments to on premise environments

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3HEo.png)

I have added variable group in my CD pipelin yaml. And in the variable group ("myvariablegroup") I have configured a secret("My_Secret").

In a build step in the pipeline yaml file, I have a 'Script' step to run docker stack deploy command using docker-compose files. In those docker compose files "My_Secret" variable is referenced but I cannot see its correclty reading the value. When I inspect env variables of the service, the environment variable which references the "My_Secret" env variable is empty.

Can someone help?

Secret variable should be accessible to on-prem agents

Comment: Are you able to provide your yaml? More then than the variable definitions which were provided.